# Cannot run Git project? Help needed for QtCreator

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, qt

Hi there I am trying to run a open source GitHub project I found.

Link to project: https://github.com/mcisek/Neural_network_GAME

I cannot run this in VS2013/2017 because it gives errors regarding Qt GUI imports.

I have tried running this in QtCreator also but when trying to create a make file I get the error "cannot run compiler 'g++'. maybe you forgot to setup the environment?"

Here is the visual studio error:

```
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QDebug': No such file or directory  c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\player.cpp   1   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   5   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QFile': No such file or directory   c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\map.cpp  1   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   9   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsRectItem': No such file or directory   c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\enemy.h  4   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsScene': No such file or directory  c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\game.h   4   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   4   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsScene': No such file or directory  c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\game.h   4   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   7   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsScene': No such file or directory  c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\game.h   4   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   8   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsView': No such file or directory   c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\game.cpp 1   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QKeyEvent': No such file or directory   c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\object.cpp   1   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   6   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QQApplication': No such file or directory   c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\main.cpp 1   1   ConsoleApplication6
Error   10  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QTimer': No such file or directory  c:\users\jd\desktop\neural_network_game-master\bullet.cpp   1   1   ConsoleApplication6
```

How can I compile and run this project?!

Comment: This is not about imports. You don't seem to have Qt in your include path. Also remember to install the correct Qt binaries for your compiler. The binaries are only compatible with the compiler version that they are specified for.

Comment: Looks like the Qt headers aren't visible to the compiler. Have you installed Qt dev properly on your machine? I don't work in VS though, so I don't know how it tries to find headers.

Comment: Also you probably need to install the addin for Visual Studio.

Comment: The QtCreator problem is probably simpler to fix. You need to select the mingw options in the install process.

Comment: In QtCreator the mingw options are changed to use gcc not g++ compiler. I dont know how to change this to get it working for qmake terminal though

Comment: Note that Qt Creator is just an IDE. It doesn't by itself contain a compiler, or any Qt version. If you installed it with the Qt online installer, then that can install different versions of Qt, and also a few versions of MinGW toolchains (other alternative is using MSVC toolchain, which needs to be dl'd from MS and installed separately). So add Qt version and toolchain for it to Qt Creator as step 1 to get this to work.